# Oracle - split table in indexed blocks

Tags: oracle

I have to deal with a little problem in Oracle...I have a table with 2 columns, the first column contains dates, the second one contains imports. The "import column" could have both NULL or not NULL values.
What I want to do is to order by the date column (and this is easy :) ) and then split the table in blocks of contiguous NULL or not NULL values in the "import column" adding a third column which numbers the blocks.
Example:

```
Date        Import
01/01/2017  99.12
01/02/2017  18.19
01/03/2017  22.92
01/04/2017  28.10
01/05/2017  
01/06/2017  
01/07/2017  
01/08/2017  33.78
01/09/2017  20.30
01/10/2017  12.33
01/11/2017  
01/12/2017  1.68
```

this table should became

```
Date        Import  Block
01/01/2017  99.12   1
01/02/2017  18.19   1
01/03/2017  22.92   1
01/04/2017  28.10   1
01/05/2017          2
01/06/2017          2
01/07/2017          2
01/08/2017  33.78   3
01/09/2017  20.30   3
01/10/2017  12.33   3
01/11/2017          4
01/12/2017  1.68    5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytic functions like this:

```
select d, import, sum(state_change) over (order by d) as block
  from
(
  select d, import, import_state,
         case when import_state = lag(import_state) over (order by d, import) 
              then 0 else 1 end state_change
    from
  (
    select d, import, case when import is not null then 1 else 0 end as import_state
      from t
  )
);
```

(NB I renamed your DATE column to D as DATE is a reserved word).

Breaking it down, starting with the innermost query:

```
select d, import, case when import is not null then 1 else 0 end as import_state
  from t
```

This adds a column `import_state` that is 1 when `import` is not null, 0 if it is null.  This creates "blocks" but they are numbered 1,0,1,0,... instead of 1,2,3,4,...

The next part compares each `import_state` with that on the preceding row, to check for changes.  Column `state_change` is 1 when there has been a change, 0 otherwise - so now the first row for each "block" has a 1 and the reset have a 0.

The outer part then simply sums the `state_change` values cumulatively to give the required result.

There may well be a simpler solution!